# Sign change detected by `signbit` vs multiplication and comparizon with zero

Tags: c++, c++11

I was doing some experiments on ways to detect a change of sign between two numbers. Given two numbers `x`, `y`, say `double` we want to know whether they have different signs or not. I have always imitated what I have typically seen

```
x*y > 0
```

But this reads not exactly like what one would normally do. It reads as multiply the two numbers and check the sign of the result. However, what we really do is check the signs of each number and decide the sign change by the usual rule. This is alike

```
signbit(x) ^ signbit(y)
```

I was curious to see if having to multiply the numbers would have some effect in the performance. I was expecting a negative effect.

When comparing the performance the former is computed faster.

I don't understand why. Is it because the compiler is able to replace `x*y > 0` by the semantic meaning of `signbit(x) ^ signbit(y)`, i.e. the xor of the sign bits of `x` and `y`? What is the explanation?

**Note:** `signbit(x) ^ signbit(y)` is not intended to replace `x*y`, but the whole `x*y > 0`.

**Code used:** (Compiled in Visual Studio)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

#define N 1000000

int main() {

    double x, y;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> y;

    bool answer;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        answer = signbit(x) ^ signbit(y);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diffBit = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();


    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        answer = (x*y > 0);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diffMult = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t4 - t3).count();


    cout << "Bit function lasted   = " << diffBit << endl;
    cout << "Multiplication lasted = " << diffMult << endl;
}
```

Comment: `x * y > 0` is not equal to `signbit(x) ^ signbit(y) > 0`, for example, take `x = 1` and `y = 1`.

Comment: @Dani I am not comparing the xor of signbits with zero. the xor of signbits already computes the change of sign.

Comment: Test code, compiler & version, command line used?

Comment: @myfirsttime1 you have your test inverted. If both numbers are positive then `x * y > 0` is `true`, but `signbit(x) ^ signbit(y)` is `0`

Comment: @M.M I know and that doesn't matter. I never said they must be equal, but that they detect the sign change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test does not do what you might imagine.

Simplifying to remove as much code as possible:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

#define N 1000000

std::pair<double, double> getxy();
template<class T> void out(T t);

int main() {

    double x, y;
  std::tie(x,y) = getxy();


    bool answer;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        answer = signbit(x) ^ signbit(y);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diffBit = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();


    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        answer = (x*y > 0);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diffMult = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t4 - t3).count();


    out(diffBit);
    out(diffMult);
}
```

Then compiling with gcc5.3 with -O2, yields the following assembler:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    getxy()
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        movl    $1000000, %eax
.L2:
        subl    $1, %eax
        jne     .L2
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        subq    %rbx, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rbp
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        subq    %rbx, %rax
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        call    void out<long>(long)
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        call    void out<long>(long)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Notice that all the calculations have been elided because they have no material side-effects.

The second loop has been entirely elided.

Comment: Interesting. so, the times I was getting are not really a comparison of the two. How can I make the compiler not to elide the second loop. What if I store the results of each computation in vectors? That is why those 100K loops were running so fast.

Comment: I stored the results of each loop in vectors and now the running times are pretty much the same. The one for `x*y > 0` only a tiny bit faster. I guess the compiler does realize that the whole multiplication is not necessary. On the other hand, I wonder how much of that remains true if the type of `x` and `y` changes to, for example `multiprecision` with many digits.

Comment: @myfirsttime1 the short answer is that it's really difficult to write "performance tests". Compilers are clever and they work out which computations are important to the result and which are not. The truth is that in reality, in proper code, as long as two methods produce the same answer and touch the same (if any) memory, they will get optimised to the point where they are indistinguishable. Therefore, worrying about which approach to take is not a reasonable concern. Worry yourself about expressing intent. Let the compiler worry about implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with or without optimisation? In C++11, signbit is an overloaded function, so will invoke function-call overheads unless it is inlined.

In any case, the expression (x * y > 0) will be much simpler than whatever signbit does to extract the sign from a double, so even if signbit is inlined, it will result in more code than (x * y > 0). I'm not at all surprised that the simpler expression is more efficient!

To get more insight into what is going on, look at the assembly of the code that is generated for each expression.